# Using regular expressions to rename a string

Tags: java, regex, string

In java, I want to rename a String so it always ends with ".mp4"

Suppose we have an encoded link, looking as follows:

`String link = www.somehost.com/linkthatIneed.mp4?e=13974etc...`

So, how do I rename the `link` String so it always ends with ".mp4"?

```
link = www.somehost.com/linkthatIneed.mp4  <--- that's what I need the final String to be.
```

Comment: Show your attempts so far.

Comment: "rename a String so it always ends with ".mp4"" `string += ".mp4"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to `split` the string with ".mp4" as a split char and then add it again :)

Something like :

```
String splitChar = ".mp4";
String link = "www.somehost.com/linkthatIneed.mp4?e=13974etcrezkhjk"
String finalStr = link.split(splitChar)[0] + splitChar;
```

easy to do ^^

PS: I prefer to pass by regex but it ask for more knowledge about regex ^^

Comment: THANK YOU for not making me use regex. Good god, I hate regex. This works perfectly fine. +1'd and selected as best answer.
P.S. The final string should = `link.split(splitChar[0] + splitChar` without the " " around splitChar

Comment: I edited ;) of course it's splitChar without the `""`
glad you liked it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just get the string until the `.mp4` part using the following `regex`:

`^(.*\.mp4)`

and the first captured group is what you want.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/zQ6tO5

Comment: So, literally do this? `link = "^(.*\.mp4");` ?

Comment: @Gregg1989, Well just read about how regex in java works and search for the regex I have given above and that is the string you want. :)

Comment: Alright :) Thanks for the quick and helpful response!

Comment: @Gregg1989, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you and Good Luck!

Comment: @Gregg1989, check out my answer too

Comment: @sshashank124 I'm having some trouble making this work :( `Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*\\.mp4)");`
        `Matcher matcher = linkPattern.matcher(link);`
        `downloadFile = new File(matcher.toString().substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));    `

Comment: @Gregg1989, Can you post your code so far in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can **also** do this:

Match the string with the below regex

```
\?.*
```

and replace it with empty string.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/iV1cZ8

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
  private String trimStringAfterOccurance(String link, String occuranceString) {

    Integer  occuranceIndex =  link.indexOf(occuranceString);

    String trimmedString = (String) link.subSequence(0, occuranceIndex + occuranceString.length() );    

    System.out.println(trimmedString);

    return trimmedString;
}
```